# Is every algebra a $\pi$ system (not talking about $\sigma$ algebra)

Tags: measure-theory

Is every algebra (or field) a $\pi$ system?

There are a lot of questions asking whether or not $\sigma$ algebra is a $\pi$ system but not for just algebra.

Since algebras are closed in finite intersection, I'm pretty sure that every algebra is a $\pi$ system, but I'm studying alone so I want some confirmation.

Comment: Yes, every algebra is a pi-system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An algebra is closed under finite intersections so is a [$\pi$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system) quite trivially, yes.